# The reward for reading khatem (finishing) Quran different in Ramadan?

Tags: quran, reading-quran

Is the rewards for khatem (finishing) of the Quran in Ramadan different or more than the khatem (finishing) of the Quran in other months?

For example, do I get more rewards when I finish reading the Quran in Ramadan?
Or is the same rewards applied all year round?

I tried to research online but could not find answers. I am asking because someone told me that anything good we do in Ramadan is always better more rewards so I was then thinking does this include finishing reading the Quran in Ramadan too that I would get more rewards.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reciting the Quran in Ramadan is more virtuous and would earn greater reward as it is the sunnah of the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ:

> كان النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم أجود الناس بالخير، وكان أجود ما يكون في رمضان حين يلقاه جبريل، وكان جبريل عليه السلام يلقاه كل ليلة في رمضان، حتى ينسلخ، يعرض عليه النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم القرآن
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) was the most generous amongst the people, and he used to be more so in the month of Ramadan when Gabriel visited him, and Gabriel used to meet him on every night of Ramadan till the end of the month. The Prophet (ﷺ) used to recite the Holy Qur'an to Gabriel
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1902)</sup>